# Laravel mass assignment security policy

Tags: php, security, laravel, mass-assignment

The `fill` method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` is used for mass assignment, and it is called by the model constructor, which in turn is called by the `create` method.
Why doesn't it throw any exception if one or more *"guarded"* attributes are found inside the input array? Instead, it simply ignores them and keeps setting the "fillable" ones. An exception is only thrown when the model is "totally guarded" (i.e. no attribute is fillable).

Let's say that even a single guarded attribute is found where it shouldn't be: isn't that suspicious enough to be at least reported to the administrators?
For now, if I want to audit such a situation and likely *cancel the operation*, I have to check the input by myself just before the mass assignment: how is this supposed to make sense?

Comment: They way you describe it it seems to be part of Laravel's code (architecture), so maybe Stackoverflow is not the right place to mention it. However, maybe you can extend the Eloquent model class and overwrite this behaviour?

Comment: The fact that one may actually override the `fill` method is out of question. I asked here because I'm trying to understand if I'm just missing something: it seems to me that the predefined behaviour is somewhat inconsistent with the goal of the "fillable/guarded" system, but this doesn't mean it is not justified.

Comment: I dont think it's "inconsistent". It's a design decision or perhaps it's just something that's still missing. L4.1 is not perfect.

Comment: That's the point: if it's a design decision then I'm definitely missing something, because it seems not aligned with the goal of preventing security threats. If it's just something that's still missing, fine, but I think it should be documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, after [some discussion](http://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2014-eloquent-mass-assignment-security-policy), it really seems to be nothing more than a *design decision* which I don't quite agree with.